# Magento 2 : Not able to override Magento_Payment::info/default.phtml

Tags: magento2, template-override

I have tried to override this template file by overriding the whole block where its called i.e `Magento\Payment\Block\Info`

But i am not able to override this file `Magento_Payment::info/default.phtml`

Is their any way we can override this file ?

Comment: Did you try to override this file in your theme ? app/design/frontend/Vendor/themeName/Magento_Payment/templates/info/default.phtml?

Comment: I am not using theme so can't do it in theme.

Comment: Did you use preference to override this block class?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i have added answer which is working.

Answer (score 1):

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Block\Info">
        <plugin name="module_paympent_view_override_template" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Block\Info" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Info.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Block;
 
class Info
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Payment\Block\Info $subject)
    {        
            $subject->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::info/default.phtml');        
    }
}
```